# build method in create action of controller is creating to the wrong user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a "review" for a specific "review request", but the way I have it set up now it creates a review for a random review request when I select the "Offer a Review" button. 
 Here's my reviews_controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.build(params[:review_request_id])
    if @review.save
      flash[:success] = "Review Created"
      redirect_to review_path(@review)
    else 
      flash[:error] = "Review Offer Sent"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def show
    @review_request = ReviewRequest.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here's a section of the partial with the link_to the create action:

```
  <span class="offer_review">
    <%= link_to "Offer A Review", reviews_path(:review_request_id), :method => :post  %>
  </span>
```

I have

```
belongs_to :review_request
```

in the models/review.rb file and

```
belongs_to :user
```

in the review_request.rb file.

This is the index action in the review requests controller. The partial with the link is in the index view.  May be part of the problem?

```
  def index
    @review_requests = ReviewRequest.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure that `params[:review_request_id]` in the `create` method are correct. If this is not, then you will not get the review requested but the other one. First make sure that it is what you chose for a specific "review request".

Comment: Please add definition of Review.build method.

Comment: @Alex - I'm using the has_many association, so from the rails api: collection.build(attributes = {}, …)

    Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

Comment: @Saurabh - I definitely think that the params attribute is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I get the feeling I'm not instantiating the params correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were actually two issues here.  I solved the first one (the review wasn't being created with the review_request_id) with:

```
@review_request = current_user.review_requests.build(params[:review_request])
```

in the review_requests_controller, and:

```
<%= link_to "Offer A Review", reviews_path(:review_request_id => review_request), :method => :post  %>
```

in the view.

I had actually solved this issue without realizing it before posting this question (and reverted back to the code above) because the redirect to the Review#show controller was wrong as well, and would show information for the wrong review_request even if the review was created correctly.  (It did this because it took reviews/1 to be the review_request_id, not the review_id)

This is the code I got that to work right:

```
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
@review_request = ReviewRequest.find(@review.review_request_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use 'puts' statement for  'params[:review_request_id]' and check what value you are getting. It seems that the problem is in the definition of the form field.

Comment: Can you provide code for that or where to find it?  I entered puts params[:review_request_id] into the create action and it did not show up in rails server.  Sorry, I'm new.  :)

Comment: write this in create action - ' puts "my id======"+params[:review_request_id].to_s'

Comment: It's coming back blank, which I guess I should've guessed since the data being INSERT INTO "reviews" shows: ["review_request_id", nil]

Comment: the review is being generated for a random review request because the review_request_id is being set randomly (as far as i can tell)